# Why is IF(AND Function not returning correct value when conditions met?

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I am trying to return a value only when two conditions are met. The function works for the first few rows of data and then defaults to the fail value. The function appears to be good, but it is simply not working on all of the rows I need it to. Here is the function using structured references.

`=IF(AND([@[PAT_MRN_ID]]=Table1[@[PAT_MRN_ID]],[@[ORIG_SERVICE_DATE]]=Table1[@[ORIG_SERVICE_DATE]]),Table1[@[CPT_CODE]],"none")`

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: Are you sure you don't have any trailing or leading spaces in either table? This can easily happen if values were copied and pasted.

Comment: This can also happen if one cell is interpreted as text and another is interpreted as a number.

Which happens sometimes when pulling data from an external source, when a number is entered as text (type an apostrophe as the first character of the cell), or when a cell is formatted as text.